# How to test my simple method in laravel

Tags: laravel, automated-tests, laravel-5.3

I have a method in laravel 5.3 project like below:

```
/**
* returns each section of current url in an array
*
* @return array
*/
public function getUrlPath()
{
    return explode("/", $this->request->path());
}
```

How can I create a unit test method to test this method? I guess I need to mock a http get request and request instance. But, I do not know how to do that.

Comment: It would be probably better if you think about the helper method being self-contained, with dependencies provided as parameters. It will allow it to be easily testable. `public function getUrlPathElements($path)` would allow you to unit test it directly without using Laravel routing mechanism.

Comment: Did you mean the method like in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781103/how-to-test-laravel-5-controllers-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your method self-contained like so

```
use Request;
/**
* returns each section of current url in an array
*
* @return array
*/
public function getUrlPath(Request $request)
{
    return explode("/", $request->path());
}
```

You can add the `Request` as a parameter to the containing class like that:

```
use Request; //it is a facade https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades 
class MyRequestHandler
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getUrlPath()
    {
        return explode("/", $this->request->path());
    }
}
```

Than test is like that:

```
public function testGetUrlPath(){
    $expected = ['url','to','path'];
    $request = Request::create(implode('/', $expected)); // https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L313
    $class = new MyRequestHandler($request);

    // Getting results of function so we can test that it has some properties which were supposed to have been set.
    $result = $class->getUrlPath();
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```